# assigning value to 3D array doesn't work?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a 3d array:
`int[,,] cube = new int[10, 10, 10];`

and the way i *thought* to assign a value it was like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j < 11; j++)
                {
                    for(int k = 1; k < 11; k++)
                    {
                        cube[i, j, k] = [i, j, k]; // Goofed up part
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: We don't know what is your problem, but I think the code throws an index out of range exception. Array indexing does not start from one, so don't iterate from one to ten. Iterate from zero to nine like this: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you want to do with `[i, j, k]`. Are you trying to add add another array?

Comment: As everyone is pointing out, C# arrays are zero-based. An array of N elements is indexed from 0 to N-1. The typical `for` loop is written `for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i)`

Comment: If you really want to store three coordinates within each element of a three-dimensional array, you want `Point3D[,,]` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Look, form your declaration, you have a 3d array of **int**s (`int[,,] cube`), that means that for every combination of i, j and k you can assign an **int**:

The correct way to do this will be:

```
cube[i, j, k] = a;
```

Where `a` is an integer

Alternatively you can change the type to the array to something else,

*Edit*

If you want every cell from array to store its own coordinates, you can change the type to `ValueTuple`.

The final code would look like this:

```
        var cube = new ValueTuple<int,int,int>[10, 10, 10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    cube[i, j, k] = (i, j, k);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: no, i want the i'th, j'th and k'th position to be i,j and k. and i dont get an error

Comment: i'm getting an index out of range exception..any idea why?

Comment: It's because you created the 3D array with enough room for 10 values per dimension, in C# array enumeration starts with 0, so we got indexes from 0 to 9, but here: ` for (int k = 1; k < 11; k++) `, you try to access the 10th index, which does not exist. To be honest I didn't noticed this before you mentioned:) , I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This will throw out of bounds exception, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I loathe using Multidimensional arrays.

With jagged collections, I could just use `Array.Count` or `List.Lenght` or a similar value as the bound of the for loop. They are way more work to initialize, but usually well worth the effort. And in your case, you are doing the loops for initialisation anyway.

As for the problem:

As CodeCharmander pointed out, your indexes are wrong. In C# Collections, Indexes start at 0. A Array or List with Lenght/Count of 10, is adressed 0, 1, 2 ... 8, 9. You will get a out of bounds exception on i=1, j=1, k=10.

Of course you *also* need to assign a single int value to a int[] element. `[i, j, k]` is not that. The simple product of the indexes is first thing I came up with.

Try this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
      cube[i, j, k] = i*j*k;
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to replace the constant 10's with `cube.GetLength(0)` (with the number being wich dimension you want the lenght for).

Answer (score 0):

## Type

When you declare a jagged array as `new int[,,]` you're saying that:

1. There are 3 dimensions (`[,,]`), and
2. Each element is a single number (`int`).

## Indexing

Your indexing is incorrect. In c# array indexing is zero-based.

From [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

> Array overview
>
> An array has the following properties:
>
> - (...)
> - Arrays are zero indexed: an array with n elements is indexed from 0 to n-1.

For this reason, a conventional `for` loop starts from 0: `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)` and if you need to put number `1-10` as value you use `i+1`.

```
var array = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   array[i] = i + 1;
}
// The array contains numbers 1..10;
```

## Example

Here is an example that creates 3 different types of cubes.

```
const int N = 10;
var cube1 = new int[N, N, N]; // Each element can hold 3 numbers
var cube2 = new (int, int, int)[N, N, N];// Each element can hold 3 numbers
var cube3 = new System.Drawing.Color[N, N, N];// Each element is a color and can hold 4 numbers

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            cube1[i, j, k] = i * 100 + j * 10 + k; // Some number
            cube2[i, j, k] = (i+1, j+1, k+1);
            cube3[i, j, k] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(red: i*20, green: j*20, blue: k*20);
        }

    }
}

Console.WriteLine(cube1[0,0,0]);
Console.WriteLine(cube1[N-1,N-1,N-1]);
Console.WriteLine(cube2[0,0,0]);
Console.WriteLine(cube2[N-1,N-1,N-1]);
Console.WriteLine(cube3[0,0,0]);
Console.WriteLine(cube3[N-1,N-1,N-1]);
```

Output

```
0
999
(1, 1, 1)
(10, 10, 10)
Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=0]
Color [A=255, R=180, G=180, B=180]
```

## An array of 10*3 numbers

If you wish to store 10 triplets of values then you need a single dimensional array of `(int,int,int)`.

```
var array = new (int, int, int)[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var x = i + 1;
    array[i] = (x * 100, x * 10, x);
}

Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
Console.WriteLine(array[10 - 1]);
```

Output

```
(100, 10, 1)
(1000, 100, 10)
```